# Help me to Identify whats wrong with this Circuit

Tags: battery-charging, lm317

I built this circuit which I found below Link

[image]

[Source Link](http://www.electronicshub.org/automatic-battery-charger-circuit/)

I used the Parts as shown in circuit Diagram.

When I connect only a battery which is voltage lower than 12V without input power source no LED's Light up and if I connect a battery full charged without input power source Red LED Light up

When I connect input power source with a discharged battery both the LED's Light up. What could be the reason for that?

Regards

Comment: It seems fine, what did you expect?

Comment: That sounds like correct operation - zener diode D6 determines when LED D3 can turn on (indicating fully charged battery).

Comment: Are you asking for analysis of how this circuit design works?

Comment: even when battery is below 12V Both the LED's Works. it should work only charging LED when its charging though. yes i want to know how this works. thanks for quick replies guys

Comment: The article describes how it works.  But the last sentence sums it up - "This circuit is tested in simulation software and may require some practical changes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple, and simply terrible, charge circuit. But I'll try to deal with it.

I'll assume you're trying to deal with a 12-volt (6-cell) lead-acid battery.

Also, your question asked when the CHARGING light goes out. For this circuit, never. As long as power is on and the regulator is more than a few volts the LED is on. So it's actually false to label it as "charging".

First, the most important part of the setup process has been left out: setting RV1. With no battery connected, measure the voltage from the regulator output to ground, and adjust VR1 for about 15 volts. Lead acid batteries should be charged to about 2.3 to 2.4 volts per cell. For 6 cells that's 13.8 to 14.4 volts total. Add another 0.6 volts (the voltage dropped by D5) and you get 14.4 to 15 volts for the peak voltage. With no battery connected, and R4 disconnected, put a meter from the output of the LM317 to ground, and adjust VR1 to give 15 volts.

Second, the voltage limit circuit (D6/R4/Q1) is horrible, and will not fully charge a lead-acid battery. It will turn on the red FULL LED when the battery has reached 12 volts. Sort of. When the battery voltage reaches (nominally) 11 volts plus the 0.7 needed to turn on Q1, the LM317 will be almost turned off, and the charge process halted. Call it 11.7 volts plus a few tenths, or 12 volts. This will terminate the charge process much too early. Plus, zener diodes are not high-precision devices unless you pay a lot of money. 5% or 10% is the standard tolerance for 1 watt zeners, with lower tolerance costing more. This will produce a nominal zener turn-on voltage of 9 to 11 volts, so the battery may stop charging at 11 volts. And finally, of course, an 11 volt zener will drop 11 volts as some specified current - for the [1N4741](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/1N/1N4731A.pdf) this nominal current is 23 mA. Since less than 1 mA will activate the cutoff process, you can pretty well count on a lower activation voltage and an undercharged battery.

You should have noted that the original link stated that the circuit had been verified through simulation. I would suggest that the author does not have much electronic design experience, does not understand the limits of simulations, and really doesn't understand batteries. Other than that, no problems.

Comment: Ahh right. Thanks for very detailed answer. yes im trying to charge a 12V 7Ah SLA Battery. currently my battery voltage is around 11.8 and Im expecting to see RED Led turn off as its below 12V but as you described it will be ON since Q1 will turn ON around 11.7V

Comment: @lasita - It may turn on as low as about 10.7, or even lower. The turn-on voltage for that zener is rated at 23 mA, and it takes a lot less to trigger the LED.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clear things up. looks like it better to find another charging circuit :(

Comment: @lasita - Try a 13 volt zener instead. The source _did_ say that experimentation may be required to find the proper component values, and they weren't kidding. Also, you don't need a 1 watt zener. A 1/4 watt should do. And the circuit will be veeerrry sllooooow in charging the battery. Charge current is regulator output minus 0.7 minus battery voltage divided by R5. So a battery at 13 volts will only get about 150 mA, and a full charge could easily take 2 to 3 days. But the link also mentions long charge times, too. Just not HOW long.

Comment: i will try that, thanks. this source parts list shows its a 8.2V Zener diode and in their video they say 9V Zener and circuit shows 11V zener. i bought all 3 and tried. so far 11V zener is what matched circuit. today i will get a 13V zener and try

Answer (score 0):

A. With no power input and a battery voltage greater than (11.0V + 0.6 Vbe + 1.? Vled), current will flow through D6 and the base of Q1 to light the red LED.

B. With power connected and a charged battery the same current path will turn on Q1 and light the red LED.  The output of the LM317 is about 1.25V + Q1 Vsat greater than the Vf of the red LED and so will always be high enough to turn on the green led. In other words Q1 turns on when the battery is charged but does not drop the LM317 output voltage low enough to prevent the green LED from turning on.

You should disconnect the battery when you disconnect the power.

A simple fix to make the green LED turn off when the battery is full:
[image: Modified ckt]

Comment: with a discharged battery which is below 12V when Power connected Red Led start to light up with Green LED

Comment: what could be the reason for RED led light up always when power connected?